# Clarifying some doubts regarding PUPDR register of the GPIO [STM32]

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, gpio

Might come off as a trivial question but when does one use Pull up and Pull down as `PUPDR` register of the GPIO? I'd guess it's used to define the default state of the pin.

The following includes the image the push button on STM32F401 nucleo board. It's apparent that `PC13` IO is pulled high via a pull up resistor in case the button isn't pressed.

[image]

So the IO pin as shown below is already pulled high, isn't it? Does it matter if `PC13` is configured to be in `Pull up` or `Pull down` mode event?

[image]

Secondly, for the LED (`LD2`) that's connected on `PA5`: if the `PUPDR` of this pin is set to pull down, there's a pull down resistor (as shown in the IO image above) that's connected to `PA5` and for pull up, there's a pull up to VDD? Assuming that's the case, shouldn't `LD2` be "on" on start of the program if `PUPDR` is set to `PULL UP`? (doesn't seem to be the case with me)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [the datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f401re.pdf), the value of both the pull up and pull down resistors is nominally `40K`. (Note that often pull up and down values may be different.)

For the case of `PC13`, note the value of the external pull up resistor - `4K7`. This is much lower than the internal pull resistors.

- If the pull up is enabled, the resultant value is `4K7 || 40K`, which is  `4K2`.
- If the pull down is enabled, then it forms a voltage divider. Because the pull down is much greater than the `4K7`, the input voltage will be above the high threshold.

They have probably put a stronger pull up here as they know it's going to be used for a switch, and has potential to pick up external interference. The capacitor `C15` also helps in this regard.

For `PA5`, the value of the pull up resistor is so high that there will not be enough current to light the LED.

Comment: Sorry, what's the value of the input impedance of the MCU though? It's usually in mega ohms (not sure about STM series) but if that's the case, your point about not generating enough current to lit up the LED makes sense. (assuming pull up is enabled, you've got 40K and MCU's input impedance in series). Not sure about your explanation on push button, and how's `4K7` greater than the internal pull which is `40K`

Comment: @Pokloha Sorry, typo in `4K7 > 40k`. Added some more information. The input impedance is so large, it doesn't matter. It will be in parallel with the pull resistor, so the effective value is going to be `~40K`. Does that make sense?

Comment: `40K || 4k7 ~ 4k7` and not `~40K` though unless you're referring to something else? isn't this what it pretty much looks with for push button (http://tinyurl.com/yddcgj6h)?

Comment: If pull up is set, I see they're in parallel resulting in `~4k7` input impedance. if pull down is set, you get ~3.3V at the input pulling it high. I'm uncertain what happens when pull up is set and when neither pull up nor pull down is set (floating). isn't R30 there to pull the pin high anyways?

Comment: @Pokloha - that's what I wrote - `40K || 4K7 ~ 4K2`. In your linked schematic, the `40K` pull down should not be connected. `R30` always pulls the pin high - as I mentioned in my answer, the reason they have this stronger pull up is that is on a pin that interfaces to the "world" (not another IC), and is more likely to be affected by interference. The stronger `4K7` pull up mitigates against that, whereas the `40K` alone might not be strong enough. Does that answer your query?

Comment: I put 40K pull down cause that's what the MCU's schematic has, and assuming pull down is ON, you form a voltage divider between 4.7K and 40K which gives you ~5V at the IO pin, no?

Comment: @Pokloha There's no switchable pull up/down on the schematic - they're internal to the microcontroller. There is `R30` as a strong external pull up on `PC13`. For the switchable pulls, you can't have both at the same time. If you set `PC13` as pull *up*, you have an effective pull up of `40K || 4K7` and if you enable the pull *down*, you get a voltage divider as I said in the answer. :)